# Proper way of calling a function in a class in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

First I have a class called `Foo` and it contains a virtual function `int Foo::getId()`

I have a typedef: `typedef std::vector<Foo*> FooList;`

Then I define `Foo::FooList *list;` and I load up this vector.

I was wondering how I would access `getId()`. Currently I am using `list[a].getId();` but the compiler keep saying `error: class std::vector<Foo*, std::allocator<Foo*> > has no member named getId`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure the vector itself has to be a pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list->at(a)->getId();
```

You could also do

```
list->operator[](a)->getId();
```

or

```
(*(*list)[a]).getId();
```

or any combination.

The `list` is a pointer, so needs to be dereferenced, as do the pointers it contains. The array operator on a pointer that is not dereferenced will add `a` to `list` - making it point to a different location.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
list->at(a)->getId();
```

Also note that your usage treats `Foo::FooList* list` as an *array* when you subscript like `list[a]`. If `a` were not zero, then it would be Undefined Behavior. Also, you should consider favoring references where possible (or values), not pointers.

`std::vector<>::at(size_t)` accesses an element of the vector, much like `operator[](size_t)`. The big difference is that `operator[]` is unchecked, while `at()` will throw if there is a range error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
(*list)[a]->getId()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a couple of pointer de-references:

```
(*list)[a]->getId();
```

`(*list)` lets you access `list` as an object, so you can call `operator[]` on it. And `operator[]` returns a pointer to `Foo`, whose methods you can call via the element selection operator `->`. You can use either de-reference `*` or element selection `->` at either place. But you should also consider whether you need `list` to be a pointer in the first place.